# Opencart how to display only 5 subcategory in a column

Tags: limit, categories, opencart

I'm new to opencart. I'm using category module to display category in left sidebar. I'm trying to add subcategory limit (say 5 in a column) same like [ebay.in](http://ebay.in) left categories.

My `.../module/category.php` file is

```
<?php class ControllerModuleCategory extends Controller {
protected function index($setting) {
    $this->language->load('module/category');

    $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

    if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
        $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);
    } else {
        $parts = array();
    }

    if (isset($parts[0])) {
        $this->data['category_id'] = $parts[0];
    } else {
        $this->data['category_id'] = 0;
    }

    if (isset($parts[1])) {
        $this->data['child_id'] = $parts[1];
    } else {
        $this->data['child_id'] = 0;
    }

     if (isset($parts[2])) {
     $this->data['sisters_id'] = $parts[2];
  } else {
     $this->data['sisters_id'] = 0;
  }

    $this->load->model('catalog/category');

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $this->data['categories'] = array();

    $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {


     $children_data = array();

     $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

     foreach ($children as $child) {            
        $sister_data = array();
        $sisters = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($child['category_id']);
        if(count($sisters) > 1) {
           foreach ($sisters as $sisterMember) {
              $sister_data[] = array(
                 'category_id' =>$sisterMember['category_id'],
                 'name'        => $sisterMember['name'],
                 'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']. '_' . $sisterMember['category_id'])   
              );                     

           }
           $children_data[] = array(
                 'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
                 'sister_id'   => $sister_data,
                 'name'        => $child['name'],
                 'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])   
              );   
        }else{                     
           $children_data[] = array(
              'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
              'sister_id'    =>'',
              'name'        => $child['name'],
              'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])   
           );   
        }
     }         
     $data = array(
        'filter_category_id'  => $category['category_id'],
        'filter_sub_category' => true   
     );      

     $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);
     $this->load->model('tool/image'); 
     $this->data['categories'][] = array(
        'category_id' => $category['category_id'],
        'name'        => $category['name'],
        'children'    => $children_data,
        'sister'    => $sister_data,
        'category_image' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($category['image'], 20, 20),
        'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
     );
  }

    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/category.tpl')) {
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/category.tpl';
    } else {
        $this->template = 'default/template/module/category.tpl';
    }

    $this->render();
}}?>
```

And my `...module/category.tpl` file is

```
<div id="menu_box">
  <div class="box-heading"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
      <ul>
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
        <li>
          <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>          
          <?php } else { ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
          <span style="float:right; font-weight:bold;">»</span>
          <a class="menuimg" ><img src="<?php echo $category['category_image']; ?> " /></a>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
          <ul class="second-level" style="position: absolute;left: 166px;top:-2px;padding: 5px;margin: 0px;width:350px; background-color: whitesmoke; border:1px solid#ececec; z-index:10;">
            <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
            <li id="second-li">
              <?php if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
              <a style="border-bottom:1px solid #5d5d5d;" href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="active"> <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <a style="border-bottom:1px solid #5d5d5d;" href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"> <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
              <?php } ?>              
                <?php if($child['sister_id']){ ?>
                     <ul>
                    <?php foreach($child['sister_id'] as $sisters) { ?>
                        <li>
         <?php if ($sisters['category_id'] == $sisters_id) { ?>   


<a href="<?php echo $sisters['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $sisters['name']; ?></a>
<?php } else { ?>
<a href="<?php echo $sisters['href']; ?>"><?php echo $sisters['name']; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
</li>
                    <?php } ?>
                     </ul>
                 <?php } ?>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
          <?php } ?>
        </li>

        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Any suggestion to do this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For main category**

**Ugly/Quick fix**

You can add this line

```
$categories = array_slice($categories, 0, 5);
```

just below

```
$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);
```

in `catalog/controller/module/category.php`

**Better Solution**

In `catalog/model/catalog/category.php` replicate the function `getCategories($parent_id = 0)` and add a second parameter `limit` to it. Use this parameter inside the query to limit the results returned

**To limit the results in children/sub-category**

**Ugly-Fix**

Add this line

```
$children = array_slice($children, 0, 5);
```

Just below

```
$children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);
```

in `catalog/controller/module/category.php`

**Better Solution**

Replicate the function `getCategoriesByParentId($category_id)` in `catalog/model/catalog/category.php`, add a second paramter `limit` to it, use this parameter in the SQL query.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Madhur. I tried your ugly/quick fix, it's displaying only 5 categories. But i need all categories to be display, but not in a single column. Lets say a category having 7 subcategories, first 5 should come in first row then next 2 should go to next row,...

Comment: For that, you need to make changes only to the view file. Adding multiple <ul> tags, one for each column. And change the `foreach ($categories as $category) {}` loop to show only 5 columns. Let me know if you need the complete code.

Comment: here http://pastie.org/5405179 You just need to remove the <ul> tag at the top and add the code on the link. Rest is to be handled within CSS to display the columns side by side or one above the other. As per your layout.

Comment: you are the man. Your code worked like a charm. Thanks a lot Madhur.